# 2x many-to-many queue from database using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is where I struggle, for example, you have a setup up 2 x many-to-many relationship with Student in the center.

You have `ClassID` and `HobbyID`, how do you list all the students (+ all hobbies and classes in the collection inside student object) that have those using Entity Framework Core, and not have to access the database multiple times or to have to queue everything.

Thanks :)

---

Edit : 
This is an example of what I want to achieve with minimum times accessing the database.

After you chose options on dropdowns (available information is ClassID and HobbyID) and click **Filter** button you should get students that have those. The students should be displayed with the rest of the classes and hobbies they have.

It is not possible to queue it all from single access to DB, how would you do it otherwise to be as effective as you can be.

Sorry if I was unclear. I am trying as hard as I can to explain this. Thank you for being patient! :)

Example design =>

```html
<span>Pick a Hoby</span>
<select>
<option value="1">Climbing</option>
<option value="2">Running</option>
<option value="3">Painting</option>
</select>

<span style="margin-left:20px">Pick a Class</span>
<select >
<option value="1">Art</option>
<option value="2">Mathematics</option>
<option value="3">Geography</option>
</select>

<button>Filter</button>
<br>
<hr>
List of students :
<p>- <b>Mark</b> has <b>Hobbies : </b> Climbing, Painting / <b>Attending Classes : </b>: <b>Art</b>, Geography</p>
<p>- <b>Jhon</b> has <b>Hobbies : </b> Climbing / <b>Attending Classes : </b> Art</p>
<p>- <b>Steven</b> has <b>Hobbies : </b> Climbing, Running / <b>Attending  Classes : </b> Art, Geography, Mathematics</p>
```

[image]

Comment: You would use loading by [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) (or other ways) which would translate into a `JOIN` when the query is ran on the database.

Comment: I am aware that Include does that but still, I am not aware how would I do this specific thing I wrote in the question. You have ClassID and HobbyID and if matched get Student object with all the classes and hobbies that he has.

Comment: Perform a query in `Students` where those IDs match if you only want the student(s).

Comment: (I am still learning) Trying to do it but not getting the result I want. If you know how would I do that, could you kindly write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assumes EF Core 5, [which now automatically creates many-to-many relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew) without you having to add an entity class for the join table (as was necessary in previous versions of EF Core).

```
// Entity classes
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Hobby
{
    public int HobbyId { get; set; }
    public string HobbyName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
      : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Hobby> Hobbies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasKey(c => new { c.StudentId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().HasKey(c => new { c.ClassId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Hobby>().HasKey(h => new { h.HobbyId });
    }
}
```

Here's a simple controller action that uses a single EF Core 5 query statement in the get action to query for students along with their hobbies and classes included:

```
private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

public HomeController(AppDbContext dbContext, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _logger = logger;
}

[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var students = _dbContext.Students
                                 .Include(s => s.Hobbies)
                                 .Include(s => s.Classes)
                                 .ToList();
        var filterableStudentListing = new FilterableStudentsListing
        {
            Students = students,
            StudentClasses = students.SelectMany(s => s.Classes).Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.ClassName, Value = c.ClassId.ToString() }).Distinct().ToList(),
            StudentHobbies = students.SelectMany(s => s.Hobbies).Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.HobbyName, Value = c.HobbyId.ToString() }).Distinct().ToList()
        };
        return View(filterableStudentListing);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(FilterableStudentsListing model)
    {
        // Demonstrates the new EF Core 5 filtered include, but you actually would not want to do this in a real app. 
        var students = _dbContext.Students
                                 .Include(s => s.Hobbies.Where(h => h.HobbyId == model.SelectedHobbyId))
                                 .Include(s => s.Classes.Where(c => c.ClassId == model.SelectedClassId))
                                 .ToList();
        var filterableStudentListing = new FilterableStudentsListing
        {
            Students = students,
            StudentClasses = students.SelectMany(s => s.Classes).Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.ClassName, Value = c.ClassId.ToString() }).Distinct().ToList(),
            StudentHobbies = students.SelectMany(s => s.Hobbies).Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.HobbyName, Value = c.HobbyId.ToString() }).Distinct().ToList()
        };
        return View(filterableStudentListing);
    }
```

Clarifying on my code comment in the post action, the reason why it wouldn't be a good idea to use the EF Core Filtered Include in any real app, is you'd be stripping out possible select options for the user to choose each time you select a filter option to filter the data. In a real app, you would just filter the students in the view model after using the exact same query as in the get action. I just wanted to demo filtered include since its the new hotness in EF Core.

Here's a simple razor view that shows the students with their classes and hobbies:

```
@model FilterableStudentsListing

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Example</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <form id="form1" method="post">
        <select asp-for="SelectedClassId" asp-items="@Model.StudentClasses"> </select>
        <select asp-for="SelectedHobbyId" asp-items="@Model.StudentHobbies"></select>
        <button type="submit">Filter</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
@foreach (var student in Model.Students)
{
    <h4>@student.StudentName</h4>
    <h5>Classes</h5>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var c in student.Classes)
        {
            <li>@c.ClassName</li>
        }
    </ul>
    <h5>Hobbies</h5>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var h in student.Hobbies)
        {
            <li>@h.HobbyName</li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Here is the simple model class for the razor view:

```
public class FilterableStudentsListing
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> StudentHobbies { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> StudentClasses { get; set; }
    public int SelectedClassId { get; set; }
    public int SelectedHobbyId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Won't that pull up all of the students from Db? 

Let's say you have 20 rows of Hobbies in the Hobby table and the same amount of Classes inside Class table.

You need all the students that have Hobbies with ID 5 and Class of ID 3, and after that, the Student object needs to have inside all the Classes and Hobbies he has in DB and not just Hobbies with ID 5 and class of ID 3.

Comment: Okay so you are trying to build a web form that has *all* of the class and hobby options but you also need to know which classes and hobbies are currently associated with the student?

Comment: I added the where filter to the first query so that it selects a single student, and therefore also that students current hobbies and classes. Then I added two simple queries of hobbies and classes. From here, you could put this data into a model class that is fed into a razor view that offers controls for editing the students classes and hobbbies.

Comment: You mention that you don't want to have to query the database multiple times for a given students hobbies and classes, and that is what the first query accomplishes. The subsequent queries are what you would need if you need to feed a web form that has selects or mutli-select boxes where you display all classes or hobbies and select the currently chosen classes or hobbies.

Comment: I edited the question, added example and maybe it will be more clearer now.

Comment: See the edits made. This demonstrates EF Core many to many relations and that you can get all the data that your razor view needs in one EF Core 5 query. I also included a post action that demonstrates filtered includes which is also new to EF Core 5.